# Batch file to Copy some lines from one text file to another text file

Tags: file, batch-file

I write batch file, and I have a problem:

I want that to write all lines from the current date until the end of the file

**example of text file :**

```
not copy this line.
not copy this line.
not this line.
5/02/2016  10 20 30 45 05 56 70 (from here )
5/03/2016  10 20 30 45 05 56 70 
5/04/2016  10 20 30 45 05 56 70 
5/05/2016  10 20 30 45 05 56 70
```

**My code:**

```
@ECHO OFF
set filename=abc.txt
set filename2=outFile.txt
set find=find.txt
set sourceFolder=c:\1\
IF EXIST "%find%" DEL "%find%"
IF EXIST "%filename2%" DEL "%filename2%"
IF EXIST "SAMPLE_text01.txt" DEL "SAMPLE_text01.txt"
set currentdate=%date%
set newdate=%currentdate:~5,11%
echo %newdate% >> %sourceFolder%%find%

findstr /g:%sourceFolder%%find% %sourceFolder%%filename% > %sourceFolder%%filename2%

set count=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('findstr /g:%sourceFolder%%find% 
"%sourceFolder%%filename%"') do (

    rem echo count is %count%
    set /a count+=1
    echo.%* >> temp.txt
)

pause
```

Comment: What is the problem of your code? Displays it all of your lines? None?

Comment: So, Your aim is to skip the 3 first lines in your source text file and copy the rest in another file ???

Comment: It looks to me that his aim is to skip the first *n* lines where the date < today's date.

Comment: hi can you help me with this code , i want that it find date of today and copy fro there until the end of the file . this batch only take the date of today and stop /

Comment: hi thank . i want that it find the date of today and from there it will copy until the eof

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the date format in your text file is the same as returned by the built-in environment variable `%DATE%`, the following script -- let us call it `lines-from-today-on.bat` -- should work for you:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "INFILE=%~1"
if not defined INFILE set "INFILE=%~dpn0.txt"
set "OUTFILE=%~2"
if not defined OUTFILE set "OUTFILE=con"

> "%OUTFILE%" (
    set "FLAG="
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
        findstr /N /R "^" "%INFILE%"
    ') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "tokens=1 eol= " %%F in ("!LINE:*:=!") do (
            endlocal
            if "%%F"=="%DATE%" (
                set "FLAG=#"
            )
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        if defined FLAG echo(!LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

To use it, call it by providing the input file as a command line argument (text file `sample.txt` in the current directory in this example):

```
lines-from-today-on.bat sample.txt
```

This displays the extracted lines on the console. To output them into another text file (`return.txt` here), provide another argument:

```
lines-from-today-on.bat sample.txt return.txt
```

Comment: I think you understood the question better than I did.  +1

Comment: Thanks, @rojo! I assumed the input file is something like a log file, so the dates are sorted ascendingly (also acc. to the OP's sample data); this allows me to do a simple string comparison (`==`), so there is no need for true (unsupported) date comparisons (`>=`)...

Answer (score 0):

Since the Batch language doesn't have a date object, I find it convenient to employ a helper language that does.  With JScript, for example, you can use the less-than / greater-than comparisons on date objects, and formatting of dates is a little more forgiving.  (Will the text files always have a zero-padded day and a non-zero-padded month?  JScript's `new Date()` constructor will work the same either way.)

Save this with a .bat extension and see what you think.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "in=abc.txt"
set "out=outfile.txt"
set "found="

rem // redirect output to outfile
> "%out%" (
    rem // for each line of the text file...
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%in%") do (
            rem // use JScript to check whether line contains a date of today or future
            if not defined found call :isCurrent "%%~I" && set "found=1"
            if defined found echo(%%I
        )
    )
)

goto :EOF

:isCurrent <date>
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%~1"
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid code

try {
    var today = new Date(new Date().toDateString()), // truncate to midnight
        otherDate = new Date(WSH.Arguments(0).match(/\b\d+\/\d+\/\d+\b/)[0]);
}
catch(e) { WSH.Quit(1); } // exits non-zero if argument contains no dates

// exits non-zero if otherDate is earlier than today
WSH.Quit(!(today <= otherDate));
```

Comment: hi thank i try it but it not work i put in abc.txt --dfsdgfs
8/2/2016 3 5 8 9
fds
dfds 
5/2/2016 1 23 4 5
6/2/2016 3 5 8 9

Comment: @user3132036 OK, I modified the script so it'll check the entire line for a string that matches your `MM/DD/YYYY` date; and if today, open the flood gates and echo that + every subsequent line into outfile.txt.  Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: hi thank allot it work fine . can you find why the code i wrote up is not work